# Opening docx file in windows-8

Tags: windows-8

I cannot open docx files which have been emailed to me.  My operating system uses windows-8.  When I try to open, the prompt tells me to  purchase Microsoft Office.

Comment: So why not purchase Office as it suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not include software for `.docx` files by default.  You can download free software to open them from http://www.openoffice.org/

Comment: Or http://www.libreoffice.org/